# android String to Int not working

Tags: java, android

Hello I am new to android and I am trying to convert a string to Int, but its not working. I am sending a HTTP GET request using Volley to server and its returning a number but android is not able to convert in to Integer

**My code**

```
     public void getRemainingTime() {
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="http://myurl.com/xxx";
        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        int myNum = 0;
                        try {
                            myNum = Integer.parseInt(response);
                        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                            nfe.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        reverseTimer(myNum);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                textTimer.setText("That didn't work!");
            }
        });
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: give your stacktrace

Comment: which is the value of response when you try to parse? can you show this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You receive non-digit character from server response. Before conversion add this line:

```
response = response.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
```

method:

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        int myNum = 0;
        try {
            response = response.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
            myNum = Integer.parseInt(response);
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            nfe.printStackTrace();
        }
        reverseTimer(myNum);
    }
```

**you can filter many ways. Here give one more, suggested by [@YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5558072/ycf-l)

```
response = response.replaceAll("\\D","");
```

Comment: To you sajib you can use `\D` instead of `[^0-9]` which mean non digits, beside @SunilMeena If this answer help you don't forgot to up-vote ans accept it as well

Answer (score 0):

Your server responds:

```
1: 
2: 34404
```

So either remove the newline the sever sends (makes no sense to me at all, why it does that)

Or call

```
 myNum = Integer.parseInt(response.trim());
```

That should also do the job.